# Encryption to decryption routine asm x86

Tags: assembly, encryption, x86

basically i have an encryption sub-routine written in asm that needs to be converted into a decryption routine in asm. The program is supposed encrypt a string before decrypting it again  to the original string.

```
       push ecx
       xchg eax,ecx
       neg  al
       ror  al,1 
       xor  al,byte ptr[ecx]
       push edx
       mov  edx,eax 
       xchg eax,ecx 
       rol  byte ptr[eax],3
       xor  dl,byte ptr[eax]
       rol  dl,2
       mov  eax,edx
       pop  edx
       pop  ecx
```

I'm having trouble writing the decryption routine. I started off by just reversing each line of the encryption (push edx changed to pop edx, etc) but i was advised this was incorrect if i wanted the string to be decrypted properly.

Could anyone tell me which lines need reversing for the decryption routine?

Here is the main encryption routine if it helps at all.

```
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    temp_char = OChars [i];         
    __asm {                         
        push   eax                  
        push   ecx
        movsx  ecx,temp_char        
        lea    eax,EKey             
        call   encrypt              
        mov    temp_char,al         
        pop    ecx                  
        pop    eax                  
    }
    EChars [i] = temp_char;
```

The program accepts an encryption key which is a random char and then encrypts a 6 character string so far.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So, as the thing encrypts, starting with plaintext byte 'p' and key byte 'k' in its initial state 'k(0)', it proceeds:

```
  a    = -p
  b    = ror(a, 1)
  c    = b xor k(0)
  k(1) = rol(k(0), 3)
  d    = c xor k(1)
  e    = rol(d, 2)
```

so to reverse this:

```
  d    = ror(e, 2)
  c    = d xor k(1)    // xor being its own inverse
  k(0) = ror(k1, 3)
  b    = c xor k(0)
  a    = rol(b, 1)
  p    = -a            // - being its own inverse
```

The issue, clearly, is that the decryption starts with k(0), and after the first byte wants to be k(1) (for the next byte), and not the other way around, so we need to:

```
  t    = k(0)           // temporary copy of k(0)
  k(1) = rol(k(0), 3)   // so same as encrytption
  d    = ror(e, 2)
  c    = d xor k(1) 
  b    = c xor t
  a    = rol(b, 1)
  p    = -a
```

Now I observe that `b = d xor k1 xor t`, and that `xor` is commutative, so the above can, in fact, be done without the need for `t`.